# Cannot create an Android Virtual Device "/dev/kvm" is not found on Windows

Tags: android, emulation, intel, android-virtual-device

I have been using Android Studio on my computer for about two years now. I recently updated to Windows 10, and have started having a few issues, most of which have been fixed.

However, now I am unable to create emulators of any phone, and Android Studio says "Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. /dev/kvm is not found. Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module."

Yet this laptop is not running Ubuntu or any other form of Linux. I have tried installing the Intel HAXM from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement but the emulator is still getting the same error.

Anyone know what I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have Hyper-v installed? [See here if you do](http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/).

Comment: @AlLelopath just checked and I don't have Hyper-v installed

Comment: I removed HAXM and then installed it. It went ok.

Comment: uninstalling HAXM then reinstalling from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager resolved the issue for me. Maybe due to HAXM updates since original post.

Answer (score 4):

I met with the same problem.
After searching for answers, I didn't get an accurate answer.
I tried in different ways. Finally, I worked it out.

First, ensure you have already downloaded HAXM, and enabled VT-x in your BIOS security settings.
Second, double click `intelhaxm-android.exe` in `\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`, install it.

This way works for me.

Answer (score 4):

So I ran into this issue also, however, VT was enabled in the BIOS and I didn't have Hyper-V.

I was able to fix it by uninstalling HAXM

> 1. Navigate to
>
>    *Control Panel* > *Programs* > *Programs and Features*
> 2. Find
>
>    *Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager*
> 3. Click
>
>    *Uninstall*

and then reinstalling it,

> 1. Navigate to SDK folder
>
>    *default path >>  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk*
> 2. Drill down to the HAXM sub-directory
>
>    *\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager*
> 3. Run HAMX installer
>
>    *intelhaxm-android.exe*

finally, I was able to launch Android Studio and run the emulator without the VT-x message.

Answer (score 1):

Either your CPU does not support virtualization, or it is disabled in the bios. Go into your bios and see if you can find a setting to enable it.